# frameset in struts

Tags: java, facebook, struts2, frameset

I am new for `Struts 2`. I am trying to develop one web application using `Struts Framework`. `IDE` is `Netbeans-7.2`.
I want to make 3 section in a page.

```
eg: Facebook "friendslist", "wall post", "group list".
```

I am trying to use `< html:frame>` tag in struts (`frameset` in `html`).

My question:
1. Can I use `frame` to achieve this feature ? if yes, could you please give some example for this..
2. Is there any other option to achieve this feature ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tiles with Struts2. **[More information](http://tiles.apache.org/faq.html)**. New version of struts2 already have tiles jar included in it. All you need is to define  configuration file for it.
[You can look more into struts2 website here](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4.1/index.html)

[**Example here**](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-tiles-example-1.html)

**Note::** From HTML5 framesets are deprecated.